# A task from Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory"

Tags: calculus, probability-theory

Chung defines a distribution function as a "real valued function $F$ with domain $(-\infty,+\infty)$ that is increasing and right continuous with $F(-\infty) = 0, F(+\infty) = 1$". Then, he defines a discrete d.f. as a "d.f. $F$ that can be represented in the form $$F=\sum_j b_j \delta_{a_j} $$
Now, excercise 3: "A plausible verbal definition of a discrete d.f. may be given thus: it is a d.f. that has jumps and is constant between jumps." [Such a function is sometimes called a "step function", though the meaning of this term is not well established.] What is wrong with this? But suppose that the set of points of jump is "discrete" in the Euclidean topology, then the definition is valid (apart from our convention of right continuity)."
The only thing I see is the fact that a d.f. that follows the "plausible definition" can have uncountable set of points of jump (though I fail to imagine such a function), when the correct definition requires it to be countable. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great counterexample to the "plausible" definition is the [Cantor Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution). It is a distribution that has neither a PMF or a pdf. The Wiki page has a nice list of very weird properties. However, one of its properties is that it is constant between jumps...yet it is not a discrete distribution.

It is an example of [singular distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_distribution) which are odd distributions that are neither continuous nor discrete nor a mixture of the two. I've never used such distributions in my practice, but they are interesting theoretical objects in their own right....